# Connect ArgoCD to insecure nexus registry

Tags: nexus3, argocd

For testing purposes, I have deployed an insecure nexus registry.

[image]

[image]

I want to access from ArgoCD to the images using http. However, by default ArgoCD expects https connection.

[image]

Adding a http in front of the `imagerepository` implies a formatting error.

[image]

I have tried to skip the issue using the `--insecure-skip-server-verification` option.

```
root@master:~# argocd repo add http://10.63.27.49:8081/repository/helm-demo --type helm 
--name helm-demo2 --insecure-skip-server-verification
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = invalid session: signature is invalid
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Hey got this one recently.
Your Credentials may be incorrect.

Either ensure login credentials are used OR change the credentials above to test.
Invalid creds will flag this message.